# wpf gridview does not have a row selected event

Tags: wpf

I have searched the internet and can't find an answer to my question. In one of my WPF XMAL pages which is a Views I am using a GridView to load and binding values for each DisplayMemberBinding row. What I need to do is raise a row selected event but the GridView does not contain that event. How do I create a row selected event for the WPF GridView?

Comment: I have looked at a few options for identification of the selected row. What are your thoughts for the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GridView` is not responsible for that, it just handles layout. You need to handle `SelectionChanged` on the `ListView`.

Comment: I understand about it being about the ListView. The SelectedItem works Best for my GridView row event. Thank you very much.